# How to fix issue with BiConsumer java telegram bot

Tags: java, telegram

After creating 3 clases: Main, Command handler and StartCommand I am getting an error with starting the project
[image]

CommandsHadler class:

```
public class CommandsHandler extends TelegramLongPollingCommandBot {

    public CommandsHandler(String botUsername) {
        super(botUsername);
        register(new StartCommand("start", "With this command you can start the Bot"));
    }

    @Override
    public void processNonCommandUpdate(Update update) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdatesReceived(List<Update> updates) {

    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Start command class

```
public class StartCommand extends BotCommand {

    public StartCommand(String commandIdentifier, String description) {
        super(commandIdentifier, description);
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(AbsSender absSender, User user, Chat chat, String[] strings) {

    }
}
```

Main class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApiContextInitializer.init();
        TelegramBotsApi botsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
        try {
            botsApi.registerBot(new CommandsHandler(""));
        } catch (TelegramApiRequestException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If I extends CommandHandler class from TelegramLongPollingBot it's working, but with TelegramLongPollingCommandBot NOT.

Could you please help to fix the issue?

Comment: Please paste your code rather than image of it

Comment: @azro done, I have added blocks of code

Comment: @ВладиславПостоян can you post the error

Comment: @deadshot done, added screenshot of the error

Comment: which  version of java are you using?

Comment: @deadshot I am using java 8